# Clear contents of cells containing any of 6 strings within a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear the contents of any cells in a specified range if they contain any of 6 strings of text. This is what I have so far however it does not seem to work, If i do it for one string only it does.

```html
For Each cell In rng1
    If cell.Value = "time" And "$ActiveCalibrationPage" And "$CalibrationLog" And "$EVENT_COMMENTS" And "$PAUSE_COMMENTS" And "$SNAPSHOT" Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
 Next cell
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction for this

Comment: Replace your `and` operators with `or`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more effective approach using `Replace`

Sample range of `A1:100`

```
Sub OrAnd()
Dim vArr
Dim vArrE
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = [a1:a100]
vArr = Array("time", "$ActiveCalibrationPage", "$CalibrationLog", "$EVENT_COMMENTS", "$PAUSE_COMMENTS", "$SNAPSHOT")
For Each vArrE In vArr
    rng1.Replace vArrE, vbNullString, xlWhole
Next
End Sub
```